# DiDom: find and edit text nodes

Tags: php

I'm studying the [DiDom](https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM) library. I need to find all the text nodes (links should be ignored) and modify them. That's not how it works:

```
$document = new Document($text);
$element = $document->find('body');

$texts = $element[0]->findInDocument("*:not(a)::text()");

foreach ($texts as $key => $value) {
    $value = "xxx";
}

echo $document->html();
```

How is it possible to do this?

P.S.: This can be done in the "[Simple HTML DOM](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/)", but I can't make a correct selector there:(

Comment: How about `findInDocument("*:not(a)::text")`?